# Component does not work at visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

If I add the component to my visualfoce page the buttons doesn't work. If I run the component alone it works.

**VISUALFORCE PAGE**

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="Con" />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:buttontest_app", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:buttontest",
                {},
                "Con",
                function(cmp) {
                    console.log("Component is created!");
                    console.log(cmp);
                });
            });        
      </script>
</apex:page>
```

**COMPONENT APP**

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:buttontest"/>
</aura:application>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    
    <lightning:quickActionAPI aura:id="quickActionAPI" />
    
    <aura:attribute name="buttonLabel1" type="String" default="new Event"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objectName1" type="String" default="Contact"/>
    <aura:attribute name="actionName1" type="String" default="new_Event"/>
    <aura:attribute name="variantType1" type="String" default="brand" />
    <aura:attribute name="isButton1" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    
    <aura:attribute name="buttonLabel2" type="String" default="new Task" />
    <aura:attribute name="objectName2" type="String" default="Contact"/>
    <aura:attribute name="actionName2" type="String" default="new_Task" />
    <aura:attribute name="variantType2" type="String" default="brand" />
    <aura:attribute name="isButton2" type="Boolean" default="true" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    
    <lightning:card>
        <div class="{!'slds-size_' + v.containerSize + '-of-12 slds-form-element'}">
            <div class="container">
                <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="{!v.setSize}" padding="around-small">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isButton1}">
                            <lightning:button class="{!v.buttonClass}" variant="{!v.variantType1}" label="{!v.buttonLabel1}" onclick="{!c.selectAction1}" />
                        </aura:if>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="{!v.setSize}" padding="around-small">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isButton2}">
                            <lightning:button class="{!v.buttonClass}" variant="{!v.variantType2}" label="{!v.buttonLabel2}" onclick="{!c.selectAction2}" />
                        </aura:if>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                </lightning:layout>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
    
</aura:component>
```

**COMPONENT CONTROLLER**

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Label 1: [' + component.get("v.buttonLabel1") + ']');
        if (component.get("v.buttonLabel1"))
            component.set("v.isButton1", true);
        console.log('Label 2: [' + component.get("v.buttonLabel2") + ']');
        if (component.get("v.buttonLabel2"))
            component.set("v.isButton2", true);
        var calcCount = 12 / parseInt(component.get("v.buttonCount"),10);
        component.set("v.setSize", calcCount);
        if (component.get("v.buttonSize").toLowerCase() == 'full')
            component.set("v.buttonClass", 'slds-size_full');
    },

    selectAction1 : function( component, event, helper) {
        var actionAPI = component.find("quickActionAPI");
        var quickAction = component.get("v.objectName1")+"."+component.get("v.actionName1");
        console.log(quickAction);
        var args = {actionName: quickAction, entityName: component.get("v.objectName1")};
        actionAPI.selectAction(args).then(function(result) {
            var fields = result.targetableFields;
            console.log(fields);            
        }).catch(function(e){
            if(e.errors){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    },

    selectAction2 : function( component, event, helper) {
        var actionAPI = component.find("quickActionAPI");
        var quickAction = component.get("v.objectName2")+"."+component.get("v.actionName2");
        console.log(quickAction);
        var args = {actionName: quickAction, entityName: component.get("v.objectName2")};
        actionAPI.selectAction(args).then(function(result) {
            var fields = result.targetableFields;
            console.log(fields);            
        }).catch(function(e){
            if(e.errors){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    },

})
```

Comment: You are missing `<aura:dependency resource="c:buttontest"/>` in your aura app. just replace this with 2nd line

Comment: @RahulGawale unfortunately it does'nt work, nothing happens when I click the button

Comment: Any other ideas? I found this ressource http://peterknolle.com/lightning-components-in-visualforce/ but i think i have everything it takes :-(

Comment: What do you mean "the buttons doesn't work"? Do they display? what happens when you click them? Do you see any errors in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: The buttons are displayed, but nothing happens when I click on them. No log files are created when I click on it.